# How to serve the default angular seed/tutorial app on the root route?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm using the [angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) as base to build an app . However when I run npm start I need to go to `localhost:8000/app/` to get the app. I would like to change the route so that I can run serve the app on the root path ( `localhost:8000/app/`) . Where can I configure  that ? I've tried to simply move the content from /app into the root but it breaks the npm/build script.

Answer (score 1):

Without running the project myself (it's Sunday after all), it looks like you would need to add the /app path to the start command inside package.json. Also check http-server docs for more on the defaults -

https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server

Other things may be relying on the root being `./`, so there may be some breakage.

[image]

Should read something like

`"start": "http-server /app --domain 0.0.0.0 --port 8000",`

Comment: I think it should be `./app` instead of just `/app`.